# Get the distance from the current location to the final destination by road like in Apple's Maps app

Tags: ios, mapkit, distance, apple-maps

I want to set start location and final destination and get how long it actually is via the roads, like in the map app. I don't know what I'm supposed to search for or what it's called. I think Mapkit is the right framework but I can't seem to find what im looking for.

Comment: MapKit doesn't have this functionality unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry dude, but MapKit doesn't have this functionality built into it.

You're best off using the Google Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses which gives you distance and driving directions.